# MYSQL like query deletes all rows from the table

Tags: mysql, database

Here is the query I used

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE dateTime like '2014-10-21 %' OR '2014-10-22 %';
```

This query deletes all the rows from the table. Can someone explain why ?

UPDATED:
This is the log

```
1   11:45:50    DELETE FROM tableName WHERE dateTime like '2014-10-21 %' OR '2014-10-22 %'  49 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1292 Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '2013-10-22 %'
```

It work fine without OR operator

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause reads `(dateTime like '2014-10-21 %') OR ('2014-10-22 %')` (my parentheses).  Because `'2014-10-22 %'` is always true, this matches all rows.

You need to compare `dateTime` in both sides of the `OR`:

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE dateTime like '2014-10-21 %' OR dateTime like '2014-10-22 %';
```

Comment: Yes it works, but my question is "why" does it delete all rows? I should give some error or something. DELETE is a very dangerous operation.

Comment: You are telling mysql `WHERE '2014-10-22 %'`, for mysql a string with numbers different from 0 is considered `TRUE`, because it converts strings to numbers when necessary. So `DELETE FROM tableName WHERE dateTime like '2014-10-21 %' OR '2014-10-22 %';` is the same as `DELETE FROM tableName WHERE dateTime like '2014-10-21 %' OR TRUE;`

Comment: Oh, just one more thing that I forgot, MySQL converts strings to numbers when necessary, and any number different from `0` is considered `TRUE`. So your `'2014-10-22 %'` is considered `2014` which is `TRUE` in boolean contexts. About your lost, Backups are important. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this Works:

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE dateTime like '2014-10-21 %' OR dateTime like '2014-10-22 %';
```

I found your syntax to be very strange. Why is your field name 'datetime'? this is a type name. Also usually like operator is not used to filter datetime fields. I think a between clause will be best on this case.